# Is my dynamic query correct and how do I check if its correct?

Tags: apex, soql, dynamic-soql

I have the query below and I need it to be Dynamic.

```
List<Opportunity> List = [SELECT ID,Producer__c FROM Opportunity WHERE ID IN :parameters.opportunityIds];
```

So I have written a dynamic query, how do I check if this query runs properly or not?

```
    String fields = 'Id, Producer__c,'
    String str = 'SELECT' +fields+ 'FROM Opportunity WHERE ID IN :parameters.opportunityIds';

    List<Opportunity> List = Database.query(str);
    return List;
```

Comment: For checking to see if something works or not, Anonymous Apex (through either the developer console, or VS Code) is what you'd use. When doing so, treat it like a unit test (you are responsible for making sure all of the data/variables you need, like a list of Opportunity Ids) are in place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will address below what you need to fix to get this dynamic query running, but you should first ask yourself *why* you are even making this query dynamic. If it is to make the list of fields scale by plugging in a `Custom Metadata Type`, `Field Set`, etc. then it may well make sense. But you should only ever use dynamic queries if you have justified why first. Treat them as a last resort.

---

No, you cannot use any dot reference in a dynamic query.

**Unsupported**

```
String soql  = '...' + 'WHERE Id IN :parameters.opportunityIds';
```

**Supported**

```
List<Id> opportunityIds = parameters.opportunityIds;
String soql  = '...' + 'WHERE Id IN :opportunityIds';
```

---

A subtler but also problematic issue with your query is that you did not include a trailing space after `SELECT` nor leading space before `FROM`.

**Incorrect**

```
'SELECT' + fields + 'FROM ...'
```

**Correct**

```
'SELECT ' + fields + ' FROM ...'
```

---

Also, as mentioned in the comments, you cannot have a trailing space in your list of fields.

**Incorrect**

```
String fields = 'Id, Producer__c';
```

**Correct**

```
String fields = 'Id, Producer__c';
```

Comment: There's also stray comma...

Comment: Could be personal preference, but I think keeping a `List<String>` with field names then using `String.join()` helps avoid those simple mistakes. That, combined with `String.format()`, e.g. `String query = String.format('SELECT {0} FROM Opportunity WHERE Id IN :opportunityIds', new List<String>{String.join(myFieldList, ', ')});` to make it harder to miss those vital spaces between keywords. Worth consideration for taking things from this answer one step further.

Comment: Oh totally agree with you @DerekF